# how do i convert my image data to a format similar to the fashion-MNIST data

Tags: r, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-datasets

I'm new to Machine Learning so please bear with me with my novice question. I'm trying to train a model to recognize benthic foraminifera based on their detailed taxonomy... here is a sample of what foraminifera look like [image]
[image]
I've been successful in doing this simply by loading my data using flow_images_from_directory (). However, i don't know how to explore the structure  of the object usually generated by flow_images_from_directory. I will like to format my data-set similar to the structure of the Fashion MNIST data. So that it easy to us the modification of the code below. I have some experience with magick package

```
dataset_fashion_mnist()
c(train_images, train_labels) %<-% fashion_mnist$train
c(test_images, test_labels) %<-% fashion_mnist$test
```

so that i have something like set which would make it easier for me to understand especially the labeling part. Also, if possible, i want to be able to append other information from CSV file to the data-set. My data is already arranged in folders and sub-folders as follows

```
data/
    train/
        ammonia/ ### 102 pictures
            ammonia001.tif
            ammonia002.tif
            ...
        elphidium/ ### 1024 pictures
            elphidium001.jpg
            elphidium002.jpg
            ...
    test/
        ammonia/ ### 16 pictures
           ammonia001.jpg
           ammonia002.jpg
            ...
       elphidium/ ### 6 pictures
           elphidium.jpg
            elphidium.jpg
            ...
```

Any help or guide to materials will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe the steps you would go through on a high level.

1. Assuming you now have a training and testing set, both with all your classes reasonably balanced
2. load your images and extract the pixel values, normalize the values so they are between 0 and 1
3. if the images are of different sizes, you should pad them so they are all of the same size
4. if you are not using a method requiring 2D structure such as a CNN, you should also flatten the pixel values
5. Associate your images (in pixel form) with your class labels
6. Now you have a set of images of fixed size in pixel form with their associated class labels. You can then feed this into whatever model you are using

Hope this helps, let me know if you're confused by any part

Side note: from your sample, it looks like your dataset is heavily skewed - lots of elphidium examples but not a lot of ammonia examples. This will probably lead to problems later on. In general, you want a balanced number of examples between your classes.

Comment: @ Andrew thanks for your comment, yes i’m Applying CNN and my database is larger than the example above. I have over 12 classes. The difference in terms of individuals between classes is not over 10%.  Sadly, i’ve past the stages of your explanation in my understanding of the problem. I want do similar formatting to the dataset above (fashion-MNIST) and that my main question. All the same, Thanks for your comment

Comment: No worries! Though I'm not sure what your question actually is? What exactly are you having trouble with?